# How to get mobile device UUID from an emulator in Kendo Mobile

Tags: kendo-ui, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, kendo-mobile

i am using the kendo mobile, i am new to it,i searched in google regarding getting the device UUID and i got it and i trying to use it,it is showing the error called
**Uncaught ReferenceError: device is not defined** need help below is my code

its working when i install in android OS not in emulator

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    var deviceUID
function onDeviceReady() {

      deviceUID=device.uuid

     console.log(deviceUID);
 }

  //app.js//

  var app;
 (function () {app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, { skin: 'flat', });}());
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the device id , you need to install org.apache.cordova.device plugin into your phonegap project using cli after in Deviceready function you need put below code.

```
device.uuid
```